# Is there a function to return specified keys of an array?

Tags: php, arrays, function

I'm wondering if there is a native PHP function to do the following:

Take two parameters: an input array, and a second numerical array of keys names, and return only the keys from the input array whose name are in the second, numeric array.

Comment: Stop wondering, start reading: http://de2.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`array_intersect_key`](http://php.net/array_intersect_key) and [`array_flip`](http://php.net/array_flip):

```
array_intersect_key($arr, array_flip($keys))
```